# Database is created but database table is not created

Tags: android, database, database-table

I have this set of coding that is used to insert the data that I've keyed in into database.
However, when I export the database,  I don't see any tables

I wonder have I done it correctly.
No error was shown too.

logcat

```
   01-21 07:55:25.567: E/SQLiteLog(772): (1) no such table: fuelLog
01-21 07:55:25.648: E/SQLiteDatabase(772): Error inserting tcost= 24 fuelprice=12 fcon= 61 odometer=123 date=12/12/12 fuelpump=2
01-21 07:55:25.648: E/SQLiteDatabase(772): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: fuelLog (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO fuelLog(tcost,fuelprice,fcon,odometer,date,fuelpump) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)
01-21 07:55:25.648: E/SQLiteDatabase(772):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
01-21 07:55:25.648: E/SQLiteDatabase(772):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
01-21 07:55:25.648: E/SQLiteDatabase(772):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
01-21 07:55:25.648: E/SQLiteDatabase(772):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
01-21 07:55:25.648: E/SQLiteDatabase(772):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
01-21 07:55:25.648: E/SQLiteDatabase(772):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
01-21 07:55:25.648: E/SQLiteDatabase(772):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
01-21 07:55:25.648: E/SQLiteDatabase(772):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
01-21 07:55:25.648: E/SQLiteDatabase(772):  at com.example.fuellog.DBAdapter.insertLog(DBAdapter.java:88)
01-21 07:55:25.648: E/SQLiteDatabase(772):  at com.example.fuellog.MainActivity$4.onClick(MainActivity.java:156)
01-21 07:55:25.648: E/SQLiteDatabase(772):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
01-21 07:55:25.648: E/SQLiteDatabase(772):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
01-21 07:55:25.648: E/SQLiteDatabase(772):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-21 07:55:25.648: E/SQLiteDatabase(772):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-21 07:55:25.648: E/SQLiteDatabase(772):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-21 07:55:25.648: E/SQLiteDatabase(772):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
01-21 07:55:25.648: E/SQLiteDatabase(772):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-21 07:55:25.648: E/SQLiteDatabase(772):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-21 07:55:25.648: E/SQLiteDatabase(772):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-21 07:55:25.648: E/SQLiteDatabase(772):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-21 07:55:25.648: E/SQLiteDatabase(772):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my coding

```
public class DBAdapter {

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
    public static final String KEY_PRICE = "fuelprice";
    public static final String KEY_FUEL = "fuelpump";
    public static final String KEY_COST = "tcost";
    public static final String KEY_ODM = "odometer";
    public static final String KEY_CON = "fcon";

    private static final String TAG = "DBADAPTER";

     static final String DATABASE_NAME = "fuelLogDB";
     static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
     static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "fuelLog";

     private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = 
             "create table fuelLog (_id integer primary key auto increment, " +
             "date text not null, fuelprice text not null, fuelpump text not null, tcost text not null, odometer text not null, fcon text not null);";

    private final Context context;    

        private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
        private SQLiteDatabase db;

        public DBAdapter(Context ctx){
            this.context = ctx;
            DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        }

        private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
        {
            DatabaseHelper(Context context){
                super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            }

            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
            {
                try{
                    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);    
                }catch (SQLException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }//onCreate

            public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
            {
                Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                        + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS fuelLog");
                onCreate(db);

        }
    }

        public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException
        {
            db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            return this;
        }
        //close database

        public void close()
        {
            DBHelper.close();
        }

        public long insertLog (String date, String fuelprice, String fuelpump, String tcost , String odometer,String fcon)

        {
            ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
            initialValues.put(KEY_DATE, date);
            initialValues.put(KEY_PRICE, fuelprice);
            initialValues.put(KEY_FUEL, fuelpump);
            initialValues.put(KEY_COST, tcost);
            initialValues.put(KEY_ODM, odometer);
            initialValues.put(KEY_CON, fcon);
        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);

        }
}//DBAdapter
```

mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button saveButton = null;
    EditText dateEdit; 
    EditText priceEdit;
    EditText pumpEdit;
    TextView costView;
    EditText odometerEdit;
    TextView fconView;
     TextWatcher textWatcher;
     String priceEditStr ="",pumpEditStr="";
     String  odmEditStr = "";
int result;
int resultCon;



        public boolean isNumeric(String str)
        {
            return str.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?"); 
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            costView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tcost);
            dateEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.date);
            priceEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fuelprice);
            pumpEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fuelpump);
            odometerEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.odometer);
            fconView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.fcon);


               priceEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                   @Override
                   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                   }

                   @Override
                   public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                      //here, after we introduced something in the EditText we get the string from it
                       if(!priceEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") && !priceEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(null))
                            priceEditStr = priceEdit.getText().toString().trim();
                       if(!pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") && !pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(null))
                            pumpEditStr = pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim();

                      if(!priceEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") && !pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                      {
                        result = Integer.parseInt(priceEditStr) * Integer.parseInt(pumpEditStr);              
                        costView.setText(" "+result);
                      }

                   }
               });

               pumpEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                   @Override
                   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                   }

                   @Override
                   public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                      //here, after we introduced something in the EditText we get the string from it
                       if(!priceEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                            priceEditStr = priceEdit.getText().toString().trim();
                       if(!pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                            pumpEditStr = pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim();


                       if(!priceEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") && !pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                          {
                            result = Integer.parseInt(priceEditStr) * Integer.parseInt(pumpEditStr);              
                            costView.setText(" "+result);
                          }

                   }
               });





               odometerEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                   @Override
                   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                   }

                   @Override
                   public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                      //here, after we introduced something in the EditText we get the string from it

                       if(!odometerEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                           odmEditStr = odometerEdit.getText().toString().trim();


                      if(!odometerEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") && !pumpEdit.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                         {
                           resultCon = Integer.parseInt(odmEditStr) / Integer.parseInt(pumpEditStr);              
                           fconView.setText(" "+resultCon);
                         }

                   }
               });


            saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveBTN);
            saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    DBAdapter dbAdaptor = new DBAdapter(getApplicationContext());
                    try
                    {
                        dbAdaptor.open();
                        String date = dateEdit.getText().toString();
                        String price = priceEdit.getText().toString();
                        String pump = pumpEdit.getText().toString();
                        String cost = costView.getText().toString();
                        String odometer = odometerEdit.getText().toString();
                        String fcon = fconView.getText().toString();
                        dbAdaptor.insertLog(date, price, pump, cost, odometer, fcon);

                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        Log.d("Fuel Log", e.getMessage());
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if(dbAdaptor != null)
                            dbAdaptor.close();
                    }
                }
            });

        }//oncreate


    }//main
```

Comment: And how you are sure that table is not created? Have you seen by using any tool?

Comment: you said the table is not created , even also said `when I export the database, I see no records in it.` how could you seen the table as empty if it is not created?

Comment: seems like bad code style, not properly capsuled insertion into db.

Comment: @ravindra.kamble I uses sqlite

Comment: @ling.s sorry, what I meant was I see no tables in the database using sqlite

Comment: @user3210263 post the error log

Comment: @ling.s I've just posted it up

Comment: Show us the code where you use `DBAdapter` class. Also there seem to be a problem where you call `DBAdapter.open()` method

Comment: @user3210263 show us your calling code to insert

Comment: @ArunkumarSharma my DBadapter code are all above

Comment: @ling.s all above .. I've share it.

Comment: @user3210263 no, you posted only the db activity, not the calling activity

Comment: @ling.s done, just updated.

Comment: remove space from 'auto increment' and uninstall then install again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your DATABASE_CREATE string, it should be 'autoincrement', i.e. without any space or underscore in it.

Also, either uninstall your app completely before re-running it or change your database version to 2:

```
static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
```

Because your code has already been through onCreate() in the SQLiteOpenHelper (you catch any errors that may occur in that method), I suspect it is not running. Doing the above should force it to do so again. Finally, remove the try/catch in your helper's onCreate(). Any failure to create the table will then crash your app at that point giving you the error you need to see in logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Which database is your sqlite pointing to?
If you are running this code on a test device, then I don't think you will be able to view that database with sqlite as is, as it would be created in a private area accessible only to your application.

You sure you are not pointing to the wrong database?

Answer (score 0):

change your create datebase query to

```
create table fuelLog (_id integer primary key auto_increment,date text not null, fuelprice text not null, fuelpump text not null, tcost text not null, odometer text not null, fcon text not null);
```

Comment: the error is the same as previous, as I've posted above. It's able to take the data, but can't insert. it's stated no such table.

Comment: change your database name & try again

Comment: I've changed 3 times already /= but still the same:( going crazy soon!